# Bias and expected value of estimator

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, bias

Definition from Wikipedia:

> $\operatorname {Bias} _{\theta }[\,{\hat {\theta }}\,]=\operatorname {E} _{\theta }[\,{\hat {\theta }}\,]-\theta =\operatorname {E} _{\theta }[\,{\hat {\theta }}-\theta \,],$
>   where ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} _{\theta }}  $ denotes expected value over the distribution ${\displaystyle P(x\mid \theta )}$, i.e. averaging over all possible observations ${\displaystyle x}$ . The second equation follows since θ is measurable with respect to the conditional distribution ${\displaystyle P(x\mid \theta )} .$

Is this a general definition of bias? Because here, we are conditioning on $\theta$, so this implies that $\theta$ is a random variable, whereas in frequentist approach, we assume that the true parameter $\theta$ is fixed but unknown, so  $P(x; \theta)$

Second definition I came across somewhere:

> where the expectation of estimator is over the data (seen as samples from a random variable)

What does it mean in this context that expectation of estimator is over data? Could you provide exact formula for $\operatorname {E} _{\theta }[\,{\hat {\theta }}\,]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition from Wikipedia seems clear to me.

An estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is simply a function of observed data $X$, i.e. a statistic. We have $\hat{\theta} = g(X)$.

Bias is taken w.r.t. conditional distribution of $X$ on specific $\theta$, so

$$E_{\theta}[\hat{\theta}] = E_{\theta}[g(X)] = \int_{X} g(x) p(x|\theta) dx, \text{ for some } \theta \in \Theta $$

To elaborate a bit, we say that an estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$ is unbiased if

$$E_{\theta}[\hat{\theta} - \theta] = 0,\ \text{for every } \theta \in \Theta$$

Comment: In frequentist statistics $\theta$ is not a random variable. You can condition only on random variables.

Comment: Also, why  not $E_{θ}[\hat{θ}]=E_{\theta}[g(X)]$? And why in second  definition given by me "expectation is over the data(seen as samples from a random variable)"? In your definition expectation is taken over different values of x and is based on some underlying "real" data generating distribution $p(x; \theta)$. So your definition of expected value is based on probabilty of "real" data distribution and "true" parameter $\theta$, not on the distribution of some sample of "real" data (estimated distribution based on sampled data)

Comment: data $X$ can be single observation or a whole i.i.d. sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$

Comment: @mokebe I think you have a problem with understanding the underlying concept of statistical model, we have a family of ditributions $\{P_{\theta}; \theta \in \Theta\}$. We assume we know what family it is, and estimate only an unknown $\theta$. I can't be more precise sorry

Comment: In frequentist approach $\theta$ is constant valued but unknown. $\theta$ is not random, it is just unknown. You can only condition probability on random variables.

Comment: @mokebe No, you can condition probability on any event, or more generaly, on any sub $\sigma$-algebra of event space $F$.

Comment: But if $\theta$ is constant then $p(x|\theta)=p(x)$ so as a result it is better to write $p(x;\theta)$ to highlight that $\theta$ is not a random variable in this case, but a parameter.

Comment: @mokebe It's a matter of preference how you write it.

Comment: ok, last  question today. Why $g(X| \theta)$, not $g(X)$ in expectation formula?

Comment: Usually it's written $g(X)$. I just wanted to mark the dependency on parameter $\theta$